# copy row based on column value and update column after copy

Tags: excel, vba

I was able to make the following macro to work which copies entries from the WorkTracker sheet from several workbooks. How do I now edit the code to do the following:
1. check column X from the individual files if it is empty or if "reported" has been updated to each cell
2. if column X is blank and columns a to w are not, the macro needs to copy the entry down to the last row where these are populated, after copying, column X needs to be updated with "Reported"
3. if column X is already populated with "reported" it should be skipped and should check the next entry

Is there an efficient way to do this? Basically the macro needs to consolidate the individual entries and also be able to identify which entries were already reported previously so it doesn't copy the entries again when the macro is run another time (which will be on a weekly basis)

Thank you so much!

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long

MyFile = Dir("C:\Users\bmsand\Documents\Agatha\FY18\Test 2\")

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
If MyFile = "zmaster.xlsm" Then
Exit Sub
End If

Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
Sheets("WorkTracker").Select
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Range(Cells(4, 23), Cells(lRow, lCol)).Copy
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close

erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Consolidate").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 23))

MyFile = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Try making your description a bit easier to read, as this wall of text is next to impossible to understand. It might help to cut your work into smaller steps. Taking one step at a time. To check if a value is "reported" you can use: If Cell(row,column).text = "Reported" then do nothing, Else do something End if

Comment: Thanks @Luuklag...and apologies for not making my description hard to understand...would you mind editing the code to show me where the condition should go? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim i as Long

MyFile = Dir("C:\Users\bmsand\Documents\Agatha\FY18\Test 2\")

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
If MyFile = "zmaster.xlsm" Then
Exit Sub
End If

Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
Sheets("WorkTracker").Select
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 4 to lRow
  If Cells(i,24).text = "reported" Then
  Else
      Exit for
  End if
Next i

Range(Cells(i, 23), Cells(lRow, lCol)).Copy
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close

erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Consolidate").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 23))

MyFile = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

The For loop I included check for the first instance that hasn't been marked  "reported" and sets the copy range accordingly. This deviates minimally from your original code, however I wouldn't recomend you using the .Select and the AchtiveSheet. As these functions are volatile and can lead to unexpected behaviour when closing a workbook for example failed. It is better to fully qualify all your objects, as was also indicated to you by Shai Rado in his answer to your question on the 31st of july.

Comment: Thank you @Luuklag! It worked...I appreciate your advise and will keep this in mind.